# Splitting strings in Python using specific characters

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to split an inputted document at specific characters. I need to split them at [ and ] but I'm having a difficult time figuring this out.

```
def main():
for x in docread:
    words = x.split('[]')
    for word in words:
        doclist.append(word)
```

this is the part of the code that splits them into my list. However, it is returning each line of the document.

For example, I want to convert

```
['I need to [go out] to lunch', 'and eat [some food].']
```

to

```
['I need to', 'go out', 'to lunch and eat', 'some food', '.']
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a sample line that you're using as input?

Answer (score 11):

You could try using `re.split()` instead:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r"[\[\]]", "I need to [go out] to lunch")
['I need to ', 'go out', ' to lunch']
```

The odd-looking regular expression `[\[\]]` is a character class that means split on *either* `[` or `]`. The internal `\[` and `\]` must be backslash-escaped because they use the same characters as the `[` and `]` to surround the character class.

Answer (score 2):

`str.split()` splits at the *exact string you pass to it*, not at any of its characters.  Passing `"[]"` would split at occurrences of `[]`, but not at individual brackets.  Possible solutions are

1. splitting twice:

   ```
   words = [z for y in x.split("[") for z in y.split("]")]
   ```
2. using `re.split()`.

Comment: the first one worked but is there a way to keep the brackets as well?

Answer (score 0):

string.split(s), the one you are using, treats the entire content of 's' as a separator.  In other words, you input should've looked like "[]'I need to []go out[] to lunch', 'and eat []some food[].'[]" for it to give you the results you want.

You need to use split(s) from the [re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), which will treat s as a regex

```
import re

def main():
for x in docread:
    words = re.split('[]', x)
    for word in words:
        doclist.append(word)
```