# Splitting strings but keeping "split" character

Tags: python, string, split

I've split a string by [ and ] but I want these characters to still appear. How do I do this?

```
words = [beginning for ending in x.split('[') for beginning in ending.split(']')]
```

Comment: Where do you ant them to appear?  In the left part?  In the right part?  In both of them?

Comment: Tagged "homework" because it's a follow-up to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203677/splitting-strings-in-python-using-specific-characters), which is tagged "homework".

Comment: I don't understand quite well what you're trying to do. Show us a test case and the expected result.

Comment: ...or in their own position in the list

Comment: Have you looked at `str.partition`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need *re.split* to do this easily:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Hello, my name is [name] and I am [age] years old'
>>> re.split(r'(\[|\])', s)
['Hello, my name is ', '[', 'name', ']', ' and I am ', '[', 'age', ']', ' years old']
```

Answer (score 0):

Would need to know more about the context of your list and what `x`, `beginning`, and `ending` are, but here are some suggestions.

You can add `[` and `]` to each item in the list, and return a new list, like this:

```
["[%s]" % s for s in some_list]
```

Or, `string.join` will return a string from the items in a list joined by a given string:

```
"[".join(some_list)
```