# Split elements in a list by character

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list that was initially a dataframe and now looks like this:

```
[['asfsd|ksjdsf|jskks','asfsd|ksjdsf|jskks','asfsd|ksjdsf',
'asfsd|ksjdsf|jskks','asfsd|ksjdsf|jskks']]
```

I don't know how to split each element in between `|` to create a new list with all of them.

I did the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv('movie_metadata.csv')
palabras_c= df['plot_keywords']
data_palabras= pd.DataFrame(palabras_c).dropna() 
d=data_palabras.T
d2=d.values.tolist()

l =[]
for i in range(len(d2)):
  x= "".join(d2[i].split("|"))
  l.append(x)
  print l
```

But I get an `AttributeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-186-a57adb3fa668> in <module>()
   l =[]
   for i in range(len(d2)):
   --->  x= "".join(d2[i].split("|"))
         l.append(x)


    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'´
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203677/splitting-strings-in-python-using-specific-characters

Comment: use d2=d.values.tolist()[0]

Comment: done! great! thank you

Comment: Welcome dude! keep coding!

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi and how can I substitute the `'|'` by a space?

Comment: change  x= "".join(a[i].split("|"))   to x="".join(a[i].replace('|'," "))

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
a = [['asfsd|ksjdsf|jskks','asfsd|ksjdsf|jskks','asfsd|ksjdsf', 'asfsd|ksjdsf|jskks''asfsd|ksjdsf|jskks']][0]
l =[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    x= "".join(a[i].split("|"))
    l.append(x)

print l
```

output :

```
['asfsdksjdsfjskks', 'asfsdksjdsfjskks', 'asfsdksjdsf', 'asfsdksjdsfjskksasfsdksjdsfjskks']
```

Comment: It gives me the same **error**:                                                                            
     `l =[]
       for i in range(len(d2)):
--->     x= "".join(d2[i].split("|"))
           l.append(x)
      

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: list don't have split method. so we have to extract strings from them.. you can copy/paste my code and run it. you won't get any error

Comment: @Crist I didn't got any error. lseems you changed variable names let me check your code that you are trying.post your code in your question as Edit

Comment: @Crist did you properly used this a= [your list][0], I am selecting 1st element from this.which is also a list. That's why you are getting that error.

Comment: @Crist I dont have pandas. If you get [[ your list]] in nested list at d2=d.values.tolist() then using d = d2[0] which selects 1st element inside it. The later part is perfectly workin okay. You try to check it at d2 ?try print d2

Comment: @Crist seems you got the answer, so you can accept the answer here

Answer (score 0):

Does `list.split('|')` not work? What have you tried?
Also, there appears to be a small error in the one item seperator

Answer (score -1):

```
l=['asfsd|ksjdsf|jskks','asfsd|ksjdsf|jskks','asfsd|ksjdsf','asfsd|ksjdsf|jskks','asfsd|ksjdsf|jskks']

word_list = []

for w in l:
    for k in w.split('|'):
        word_list.append(k)

print word_list
```

Output:

```
['asfsd', 'ksjdsf', 'jskks', 'asfsd', 'ksjdsf', 'jskks', 'asfsd', 'ksjdsf', 'asfsd', 'ksjdsf', 'jskks', 'asfsd', 'ksjdsf', 'jskks']
```